# Visual Studio 2019: Add Snippet for New/Unknown Language (NOT VS Code)

Tags: visual-studio, code-snippets, visual-studio-extensions

I've added syntax highlighting to my new language by adding my *.tmLanguage file here:

`C:\Users\<user>\.vs\Extensions\<new lang>\Syntaxes`

and now I'm trying to add my own snippets, but nothing seems to work.  I'd like to use a *.json file but if I need to make individual *.tmSnippet files that's fine too I'll take anything at this point if it works.

I know it's possible because I've found the Extension [Syntax Highlighting Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SyntaxHighlightingPack) by Mads Kristensen and although his repo is open source I still can't figure out how he makes it work.

Things I've tried:

1. Cloning the [Syntax Highlighting Pack](https://github.com/madskristensen/TextmateBundleInstaller) repo and adding my language and snippets.

.......Result: VS errors when I try to load and I don't know how to troubleshoot.

2. [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/walkthrough-creating-a-code-snippet?view=vs-2019)

.......Result: according to the documentation I need to know the Language attribute but it's not one of the 9 languages listed so I don't know how to make that work.

3. Installing the [Syntax Highlighting Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.SyntaxHighlightingPack) and then using the snippets it adds as a template.  Note: There are several formats for snippets and I've tried them all. (*.tmSnippet, *.plist, and *.json)

.......Result: Adding the *.tmLanguage this way works but Snippets file no matter the format seems to be ignored.

Comment: I too am trying to find a way out. Please post back your solution in case you had your way forward on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the tmSnippet file properties : Build action = Content, Include in VSIX = true.

Take a look to Mads's demonstration : [Writing Visual Studio Extensions with Mads - Supporting new Languages with TextMate Grammar Files](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ftug7sL-5kw)